# Cognito/IAM Policies & S3 Get Object

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to integrate S3 and Cognito into my iOS App, so far not successfully. I believe the error is connected to my IAM Policy for Auth and Unauth users. So here's my policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":
   [{
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":"cognito-sync:*",
    "Resource":["arn:aws:cognito-sync:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:identitypool/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}/identity/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
  },
  {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"]
  }
 ]
}
```

here is where I call S3:

```
    AWSS3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest = [[AWSS3GetObjectRequest alloc] init];
    getObjectRequest.key = KEY;
    getObjectRequest.bucket = BUCKET;

    //default service has been configured previously
    AWSS3 *s3 = [[AWSS3 new] initWithConfiguration:[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration];

    [[s3 getObject:getObjectRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if(task.error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Got File");
            NSData *data = [task.result body];
            NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
            }

        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

and here is the error:

Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain Code=0 "AccessDenied -- Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity" UserInfo=0x10a23e0a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=AccessDenied -- Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity}

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi my friend.

As far i can see you are not properly authenticated. Please show how you use authentication  that is provider by cognate.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are experiencing

```
Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
```

Is due to an error in your trust policy, not your access policy.

Is this the role that was created as part of the Cognito setup wizard? Did you modify the role in any way? The role created by the Cognito console is pinned to the specific identity pool it was created with. Make sure you are using the role that was created with the identity pool you are using in your application.

Comment: I have the same issue- and my role was created with the wizard. What is a trust policy we can use to do this very simple thing?

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom did you create a new pool with the same name as a previous pool? Unfortunately there was an issue where the console would not be able to update roles based on the new pools identity pool id. [This blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies) shows example trust policies for use with Cognito. These must be set via the [IAM console](http://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/).

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom Can you post a new question with details of your configuration? Or perhaps on our forums so we can get access your account details?

Comment: Sure- posted this yesterday (and solved it) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178541/not-authorized-to-perform-stsassumerolewithwebidentity-aws-s3-cognito-auth-fail  but would love to know your thoughts. My solution- the s3 bucket wasn't "US Standard" and 2 other changes.

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom Added an answer to that post. Hopefully it helps clarify things.

Comment: @BobKinney Thank you for your comment about creating a new pool with the same name as a previous pool. That's exactly what I did, and I was running into the same issue as the OP. I created a brand new pool with a different name and used the new identity pool ID and role IDs, and my code is working great!