# Dynamic AuthRole for Cognito in iOS App

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am currently looking into implementing the Cognito solution within my iOS app. Now, the only problem that I see is the following:

I have multiple clients using my app, and each of one of them has their own bucket. I currently have multiple IAM Roles for each and one of them of these buckets. (Confidentiality)

When I look at Cognito, it seems like I have to hardcode the AuthRole that I will want my users to use when making requests to my buckets. In that perspective, my current structure does not work, and I am not sure that I want **one** role that can access (at least just read) all my clients buckets images and videos.

Is there a way I can go around this problem? The other possibility that I see is that I create some kind of server that requires that one basic hardcoded AuthRole in my iOS app, and depending on the users parameters, it returns their respective AuthRole for their respective bucket and ec2 instances. Is that something that should be considered?

Note that I have one iOS for all my clients.

Thanks!

Note #2: I tried looking at some examples of a Token Vending Machine for temporary credentials... but nothing turned out great, it terms of tutorials and samples! I am using a Django backend.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Cognito/IAM Policies & S3 Get Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309516/cognito-iam-policies-s3-get-object). The trick is to use variable ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}. You can limit that identity to access resources under its own namespace. If you plan to access DynamoDB, here is an article you want to read:
[Fine-Grained Access Control for DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html)

Comment: What I mean is that I want each role, to only be restricted to one specific. (X Roles, for X buckets, for X clients). Therefore, I can create one pool, but how do I give back the good role to the good client? That is where my vending identity machine comes in right?

Comment: @abisson it is not necessary to create a token vending machine for this purpose. Even though you only get 2 roles by default you can create and use more if you want with your app.