# aws S3 Transfer Manager Demo shut down

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to run the AWS android samples from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples

I have included the following jars in libs:

- aws-android-sdk-2.0.4-cognito.jar
- aws-android-sdk-2.0.4-core.jar
- aws-android-sdk-2.0.4-s3.jar

Also I have added the `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID, COGNITO_POOL_ID, COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH, BUCKET_NAME`

this is the  logcat
[image: logcat screenshot]

When im runnig this sample, action and then program shuts down.
What is problem?
I don't know what to do.

Comment: Just read the exception. You have not correct data. It must be shorter than 15 chars - not sure which caouse i didnt worked with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace shows `accountId` is malformed. The `accountId` isn't your login email of your AWS account. Instead, it should be a 12 digit account number. One way to find it is to go to console -> `My Account` (top right corner).

PS: consider use the latest SDK version v2.2.2. It has lots of improvements compared to v2.0.4. You can find it at http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.
If you do not mind I ask you.
to upload an image is not transfer. what is needs?

Comment: And i touch download button then shut down.

Comment: This blog post (http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication) explains 'Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'. This is also answered in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178541/not-authorized-to-perform-stsassumerolewithwebidentity-aws-s3-cognito-auth-fail. If you have further question, please create a new question.