# Not authorized to perform AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity with Cognito User

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, policy, amazon-cognito

With [AWS-Cognito-Identity-Js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js]) I obtain a session ID token `session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()` for a authenticated Cognito User.

I pass this `token` to my `AWSInitialize` function and update the AWS Credentials:

```
var AWSInitialize = function(token){
  Logins = {};
  Logins['cognito-idp.' + AWSCognito.config.region + '.amazonaws.com/' + poolData.UserPoolId] = token;

  AWS.config.update({
    region: AWSCognito.config.region,
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId : identityPoolId,
        region: AWSCognito.config.region,
        Logins : Logins
    })
  });
};
```

This works correctly because now for example I can execute a Lambda-Function on behalf of an authenticated Cognito User.

```
 var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({});
 lambda.invoke({FunctionName: 'createToken'}, function(err, data) ...
```

This is possible because in the `Cognito_myAppAuth_Role` I attached a Policy that allows me to Execute this Lambda-Function:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1471300653000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:593845191076:function:createToken"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Now what I am trying to do Is to get Tokens with STS for the same users**

For that I attached another policy to `Cognito_myAppAuth_Role`. It should allow the Cognito Users to call `assumeRoleWithWebIdentity`:

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1472560044000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**But when I run this code:**

```
var sts = new AWS.STS({});

var params = {
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::593845191076:role/Cognito_myAppAuth_Role', /* required */
  RoleSessionName: "UserName", /* required */
  WebIdentityToken: token, /* required */
};

sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

**I get the following error:**

```
  AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
```

**I do not understand why the user is not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity. To the authenticated Role I attached a STS policy and the Lambda-Policy was also working for the User**

**Where could be the problem?** **How can I solve this issue?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify, those policies are attached to the same role? Are you running this with the same user/identity? And why are you using STS manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the reason for this failure is that you are trying to use the Cognito Your User Pool token directly with STS. While I no longer work directly on Cognito, I do not believe this will work.

You should try one of the following:

1. (**recommended**) Use the Cognito federated identity calls `GetId` and `GetCredentialsForIdentity` to get your temporary credentials. This is what your first block of code is doing under the hood.
2. Use the Cognito federated identity calls `GetId` and `GetOpenIdToken`, then use **that** token in your `AssumeRoleForWebIdentity` call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @BobKinney, thanks for your answer. I assumed that in order to call AWS API Gateway as Cognito User, first I would have to get his AWS Credentials. I thought the Credentials are necessary to construct the Authenticated-Header. But I could figure out that authenticated calls to AWS API Gateway as Cognito-User are different from calls as IAM-User. It was sufficient to pass the Cognito-Users `session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()`-Token in the Header, Credentials were not necessary. Are there any security concerns? Have a great day!

Comment: @JohnSmith bearer token security is not nearly as strong as the HMAC signature used in SigV4. If someone accesses the token in flight they can make any request they want to your API. As long as communication to the endpoint is SSL (which is required for API Gateway) and the client is secure, this can be mitigated.

Comment: thanks for taking your time and explaining the issues. Have a great day!